# Как с помощью bower и gulp собрать проект, если в компоненте есть ссылки на его иконки?

Tags: html, css, файлы, gulp, bower

Я разобрался немного в `gulp` и `bower`. Но возник вопрос.

А если компонент например такой как `Bootstrap`, `fancybox` или `fontawesome` имеет в своем `css` файле ссылку на иконки или на изображения.

Ты берешь все файлы минифицируешь, склеиваешь и в продакшене у тебя файловая структура уже другая. А адреса в `css` на иконки остаются прежними.

И как теперь каждый рас лезть в `css` и менять адрес иконок? или всю папку `bower_components` тащить на сервер, что бы структура не менялась и не склеивать?

**Как организовать структуру, если одни файлы зависят от других?**

пожалуйста помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папку для сборки нужно перенести картинки и шрифты так чтобы ссылки в css не заметили подставу.

Например при исходной структуре:

```
 - bootstrap/css/file1_bootstrap
 - bootstrap/css/file2_bootstrap
 - bootstrap/images/file1_bootstrap
 - bootstrap/images/file2_bootstrap
 - bootstrap/fonts/file1_bootstrap

 - otherComponent/css/file1_otherComponent
 - otherComponent/css/file2_otherComponent
 - otherComponent/images/file1_otherComponent
 - otherComponent/images/file2_otherComponent
 - otherComponent/fonts/file1_otherComponent
```

Структура после сборки:

```
- build/css/vendor.css // де весь собранный css
- build/images/file1_bootstrap
- build/images/file2_bootstrap
- build/images/file1_otherComponent
- build/images/file2_otherComponent
- build/fonts/file1_bootstrap
- build/fonts/file1_otherComponent
```

Если например в папке с изображениями есть под папки, то нужно в новой структуре их так же разложить.

Comment: Отличный ответ на вопрос как это сделать